# Loading indicator after clicking button

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, web-applications

I'm wanting to show a loading indicator after the user has clicked a button that executes several SQL queries. I tried unhiding a div on button click but that doesn't show up until all the work behind the button is complete. I also tried this solution without success - http://forums.asp.net/t/1608046.aspx/1

Any suggestions?

`code`

```
<asp:Button ID="loadButton" OnClientClick="ShowDiv()" runat="server" 
onclick="loadButton_Click" Text="Go" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowDiv()
    {setTimeout('document.getElementById("updatediv").style.display = "inline";', 500);}}
</script>


<div ID="updatediv" runat="server" >
<img src="Images/ajax-loader.gif"  /> Updating ....
</div>
```

`code`

I get the following error when using the linked solution above:
[image]

**This seemed to do the trick

`code`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ShowDiv()
   $('#updatediv').show() }
</script>
```

`code`

[image]

Comment: You need to show code in order to get some help here. Otherwise it's shooting in the dark, and doesn't show that you've actually attempted anything.

Comment: @Blake-For the update you need to use ajax.

Comment: I'm not using an ajax call... can I not provide UI feedback without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have the show div on the client side, not the server side.  ASP buttons have a handy `OnClientClick` in addition to the server side `Click` event.

This is of course what the link that you show does.  If you followed it, then it shouldn't be waiting to finish the postback to execute.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        #UpdateProgress1 { 
            top:450px; left: 450px; 
            position: absolute; 
            background-color: #C3E1FF; 
           background-repeat: repeat-x; } 
</style>
```

Add scriptMananger,UpdatePanel as shown:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                <table runat="server" border="1" width="98%" align="center">
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                </table>
                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <img src="Images/Loading.gif" /><br /><center><font color=red>Processing Data...</font></center>
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnprocess" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then give some timer

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

If you're using Simple JQuery you need to do ajax way and here is how you should do with ajax:

```
$('#ShowDiv')
    .hide()  // hide
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: I like this solution, if the OP is using an UpdatePanel.  It's not clear whether or not he is.

Comment: @Sevy-Thanks for that.If he uses or not he might mention it clearly but from our end I have given him the possibility to do so :)

Comment: It's a great solution worth posting, regardless of whether OP can use it; I wasn't criticizing your posting it.

Comment: @Servy-Thanks that you liked it :)

Comment: Can we get a jsfiddle for the output sir?

Comment: @laurence keith albano- jsfiddle dosent support asp.net :(